# How do I display text in a .txt file with an async function with jsonp?

Tags: javascript, async-await, text-files

I'm trying to display texts from an API, that's a .txt file.
It may have something to do with

```
async function load_url() {
let response = await fetch("<txt file>");
```

But I do not know what to do for the rest.

Also what is the code for retrieving online a certain line? Like, how would I retrieve just "Fish" in a .txt file that's just this?

> Cat
> Fish
> Giraffe
> Bison

Answer (score 0):

You should use a json file, Homewhere, we need to know which language do you use for your backend

Edit :

If the API retur you a text file, you can do that :

```
    var lines = this.response.split('\n');
    for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
      console.log(lines[line]);
      //If you want to show a specific line, just give the correct index
    }
```

Edit :

You just dont have any response by your request

Comment: I use Javascript.

Comment: Hello, I updated my code in my latest comment. Please have a look.